# New Feature to Let Users Select Questions to Revisit/Private Tags?

Tags: feature-request, tags, user-accounts, question-lists

I've been answering lots of questions on WordPress Answer but I'm also managing to forgot to revisit many questions for which I had planned to return to elaborate. Problem is there's no really easy way to keep track of them other than me to keep a bookmarked list, and well I guess I'm just not disciplined enough for that.

I'd love to have a private list of questions that I could add to simply by clicking a button on the question with a label like *"Add to Revisit List"* or similar. It would be nice if when I click the button I'd have the option to add one line of notes about the question so that I can remember why I tagged it to be revisited.

And while I'm wishing, it would be nice to have a section in my account management area where I could review this list of questions and set priority (so I could sort by priority) and an optional date to revisit. That way when I have free time I could visit that page and tackle the one at the top of my list if there are not other good questions pending that I have the expertise to answer.

While I'm writing this it also occurs to me that maybe **if we had private tags** it would give us those features and more *(private tags would be tags I can assign to any question but that only I can see.)*

Comment: Use the "favorite" option - the star under the vote count.

Comment: Workaround: Your profile shows a list of all your answers. Sort them by "newest". Even prioritisation is implemented: Care about the ones with low vote count first.

Comment: Which doesn't include questions/answers you've just commented on, nor anything you think "I've got an idea for that, but it's pretty indepth and no time to answer now".

Comment: *@ChrisF* - The Favorite option is all wrong. It's not a favorite, it's one I want to revisit; there's a *huge* difference between the two.

Comment: @Ladybug Killer - Thanks for the suggestion but that doesn't really help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure tags make sense for what you're asking for - unless you can elaborate on the different type of tags you would use?

What you want is bookmark functionality - just like a browser, but limited to the context of the SE site you're on.

There is already *half* of this functionality in place - the star next to a question indicates "favorite", which is what Microsoft/IE uses for what every other browser calls "bookmark", and it seems the SO team has copied this confusing terminology.

Once added, you can view your <del>bookmarks</del>favorites by going to your profile (click name at top middle) and selecting the "favorites" tab (third from right), which lets you sort by various criteria.

Of course, what SO currently lacks is the ability to change the title and/or add a description, plus a decent way to explore/filter bookmarks.

If this functionality was augmented to allow a description, and there was a way to search/filter the bookmarks shown based on this description (and title/tags of the question), then I think you'd basically have the tools to do what you're asking?

The search box in the top right allows you to limit a search to your bookmarked questions, by using `infavorites:mine`, however this does not display a nice tidy list of questions (like the profile page does), but instead shows both questions and answers, with a two-line unformatted summary for each, all muddled up together.

Oh, and the other problem (in the context of your request) with the whole favorites thing is that it's not private - anyone can view anyone else's favorites - which is slightly odd really. Not necessarily a privacy concern on programming sites, but I do wonder if there are other SE sites where that might not be the desired functionality.

Comment: *@Peter Boughton* - Yes, *"tagging"* as a solution was an afterthought after I wrote up the issue. *"Bookmarking"* specifically within SE is what I am looking for. But I really don't want to use a feature called *"favorites"* for bookmarking; I'd like my favorites list to be a list of questions that are like, well, my favorites and not one I want to revisit. If it were augmented as you say *and* I could create multiple *"favorite"* lists *and* it were private, then yeah. But what's here currently doesn't address the issue as you do point out, especially the part about privacy.